# Conversion Failed varchar Value

Tags: sql, casting, type-conversion, varchar

```
   SELECT  
    ClientID,
    ProfileID as [Profile ID],
    Title,Name as [First Name],
    Surname as [Last Name],
    Lender,
    Product,
    LoanAmount as [Loan Amount],
    DateCompleted as [Mortgage Completed Date],
    Source as [Lead Source],
    ERC as [Erc Date],
    Casetype as [Case Type],
    email,
    HouseNameNum as Street,
    Address1 as Street, 
    Address2 as Street,
    Town as City,
    (postcode1 + postcode2) as Postcode,
    CAST('http://172.16.200.119/BPSAdmin/Legacy/CommTracking.aspx?ClientId='+ ClientID AS VARCHAR(100)) as [Perspectives Comms]
FROM Datatable
```

The error I receive is:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value

'http://172.16.200.119/BPSAdmin/Legacy/CommTracking.aspx?ClientId=' to data type int

ClientID is an INT, however, I want to add some strings to the beginning of the field to create a hyperlink to the clients' file.

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to explicitly cast the client Id column by itself so just shift your cast over: `'http://172.16.200.119/BPSAdmin/Legacy/CommTracking.aspx?ClientId='  + cast(clientid as varchar)`

Answer (score 1):

Adding url outside the cast, so that it cast function work and convert `Int` to `varchar`

Becuase Int and string cannot be concatenated, it is required the same datatype.

```
SELECT  
    ClientID,
    ProfileID as [Profile ID],
    Title,Name as [First Name],
    Surname as [Last Name],
    Lender,
    Product,
    LoanAmount as [Loan Amount],
    DateCompleted as [Mortgage Completed Date],
    Source as [Lead Source],
    ERC as [Erc Date],
    Casetype as [Case Type],
    email,
    HouseNameNum as Street,
    Address1 as Street, 
    Address2 as Street,
    Town as City,
    (postcode1 + postcode2) as Postcode,
    'http://172.16.200.119/BPSAdmin/Legacy/CommTracking.aspx?ClientId='+ CAST( ClientID AS VARCHAR(100)) as [Perspectives Comms]
FROM Datatable
```